# Restore object from XML with a duplicated XmlElementAttribute name

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have a object with this kind of structure:

```cs
    public class XMLTagDataSection
    {
        [XmlElement("Type", Order=1)]
        public EnuDataType XML_type  { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Value", IsNullable = false, Order = 2)]
        public string XML_Value      { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Value", IsNullable = false, Order = 3)]
        public XMLTagValue Tag_Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class XMLTagValue
    {
        [XmlElement("Variable", IsNullable = false, Order = 4)]       
        public int   Variable { get; set; }
    }
```

To generate  XML files like that:

Case #1:

```
    <Data>
      <Offset>0</Offset>
      <Type>ASCII</Type>          
      <Value>
        <Variable>1</Variable>
      </Value>
    </Data>
```

Case #2:

```
    <Data>
      <Offset>0</Offset>
      <Type>ASCII</Type>          
      <Value>TestString</Value>
    </Data>
```

my actual problem is that i cant deserialize the two diffrent value tags proper back to an object.

Comment: Short answer: don't use this schema.

Comment: Although the question is interesting, I need to agree with @user2864740.

Comment: Have you tried including both `Value` elements in the one XML structure? It's probably never going to work if you only ever provide one (how will the deserializer know which one you are looking for). The best solution would be to differentiate the element names to something that distinguishes both separately.

Comment: Mid-length answer: One way this can be accomplished is to have a *single* `Value`-named property of type `XmlNode[]` *or* of a type that implements `IXmlSerializable`. Then it's your responsibility for providing the desired custom mapping (e.g. the contents of the Value node) as appropriate. Non-serialized (`XmlIgnore`) properties can act as wrapping accessors.

Comment: Try to create an xsd first. If you are able to create one which validates your xml then (except some situations) you can use xsd.exe from VS prompt to generate the entire xml handling automatically. I would suggest this approach as you may benefit from it instead of writing code that can be better auto generated.

Comment: @James: the XML structure is fix defined. is there no possibility to seperate the tags by its structure?

Answer (score 0):

my own thought to differ the valu tags was somthing like that;

```
    [XmlInclude(typeof(XMLTagValue)), XmlInclude(typeof(XMLValue))]
    public class XMLTagDataSection
    {
        [XmlElement("Offset")]
        public int XML_Offset        { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Type")]
        public EnuDataType XML_type  { get; set; }

        public object Tag_Value      { get; set; }
    }

    public class XMLVariable
    {
        [XmlElement("Variable", IsNullable = false)]       
        public int   Variable { get; set; }
    }

    public class XMLValue
    {
        [XmlElement("Value", IsNullable = false)]
        public string XML_Value      { get; set; }
    }
```

but in this case the object Tag_Value become a own tag in the XMLfile.
is there a way to enable this behaviour of the xmlserializer